# Working with Backgroundworker

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

I want to load a text file in `WPF-RichTextbox` using `BackgroundWorker`

Here is my code :

```
    private delegate void update();

    private void reader()
    {
        StreamReader str = new StreamReader("C:\\test.txt");
        while (!str.EndOfStream)
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText(str.ReadToEnd());
        }

    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        progress wnd = new progress();
        BackgroundWorker bg = new BackgroundWorker();
        bg.DoWork += delegate(object s, DoWorkEventArgs args)
        {

            update up = new update(reader);
            richTextBox1.Dispatcher.Invoke(up);

        };

        bg.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate(object s, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
        {

            wnd.Close();
        };

        wnd.Show();
        bg.RunWorkerAsync();



    }
```

and for progress.xaml :

```
   <Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.progress"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="progress" Height="192" Width="452" ResizeMode="NoResize" ShowInTaskbar="False" Topmost="True" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowStyle="None">
<Grid>
    <Label Content="loading ...." Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="46,32,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <ProgressBar Height="29" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="46,78,0,0" Name="progressBar1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="325" IsIndeterminate="True" />
</Grid>
```

When I set `wnd.showdialog()` , it shows the indeterminate status of progress bar but the application does not load any text .

When I set `wnd.show()` , it loads the text but when loading , the progress bar freezes and 
does not show indeterminate status.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT :

due to Servey and SLaks answers , i have updated the code but it has the same problem (it loads the text but when loading , the progress bar freezes and does not show indeterminate status.)

what is the problem? here is my updated code :

```
           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();



    private void reader()
    {
        StreamReader str = new StreamReader("C:\\test.txt");
        while (!str.EndOfStream)
        {

            sb.Append(str.ReadToEnd());

        }

    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        progress wnd = new progress();
        BackgroundWorker bg = new BackgroundWorker();
        bg.DoWork += delegate(object s, DoWorkEventArgs args)
        {



            reader();

        };

        bg.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate(object s, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText(sb.ToString());
            wnd.Close();

        };

        wnd.Show();
        bg.RunWorkerAsync();


    }
```

Comment: You aren't actually doing any of the work in the background.

Comment: @SLaks : really ? why ? can you more provide more details ? thanks

Comment: What do you think `richTextBox1.Dispatcher.Invoke` does?

Comment: i think it freezes the richtextbox1 to do some action e.g. for appending text .... if i am wrong , please let me know. thanks.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh199416(v=vs.110).aspx It runs code _on the UI thread_.

Comment: @SLaks : thanks , i have updated the code but the problem remains !

Comment: I don’t see a `ProgressBar` control anywhere in your code, and you have to update progress in a `ProgressChanged` event. `RunWorkerCompleted` gets raised only after the BackgroundWorker is finished.

Comment: @DourHighArch : i do not want to report progress. the progressbar is in determinate to show only that the process is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've had a look at your uploaded code and your problem is most probably with how you're doing the loads. As far as your loading goes, the following code does the job as you want it to:

### MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Loaded += OnLoaded;
}

private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
{
    Loaded -= OnLoaded;

    var wnd = new ProgressWindow();
    var dispatcher = wnd.Dispatcher;

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        using (var stream = new StreamReader("C:\\test.txt"))
            return stream.ReadToEnd();

    }).ContinueWith(x =>
    {
        //Main window dispatcher
        Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() => richTextBox1.AppendText(x.Result)));

        //progress window dispatcher
        dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.DataBind, new Action(wnd.Close));
    });

    wnd.ShowDialog();
}
```

While this works as intended, the freeze will happen regardless (i had a freeze of several seconds loading an 800kb text file). The problem is your use of RichTextBox. Judging by your code, you have no idea how wfp works and you're trying to work in a typical winform style.

`RichTextBox` in Wpf is very different from winforms `RichTextBox`. Similarly, a `TextBlock` is very different from a typical `Label`. If all you want is color and other formatting options, a `TextBlock` is very capable of doing that on its own and is far faster than building `RichTextBox` the way you're building.

If you must build `RichTextBox` from a text file, you need to learn about `FlowDocument` and how to create one from a text file yourself in order to avoid the freeze. The alternate to this solution will be running two UI threads (one for each window) and you're very likely to find that a lot more hassle than its worth.

Before attempting this sort of thing, you should sort your WPF basics out and learn the typical MVVM pattern before taking a dive into threaded WPF world. And again, avoid RTB in WPF if you can. The base controls in WPF are far more powerful than their winforms counterparts if you know how to use them.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer , i wil keep it in my mind. +1 vote up for you.

Comment: You're very welcome. You can also come over to [WPF channel](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf) where I'm online pretty much everyday along with some other very capable folks if you need any quick directions.

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually doing any work in the background.  You're starting a background worker and the the only thing that the worker is doing in the background is scheduling an operation to run on the UI thread, and that operation is where you do all of your non-UI work.  Since you're doing non-UI work on the UI thread, no other graphical operations can be performed until it finishes.

You'll want to read from the file in the BGW's do work event, store it in memory, and then in the Completed event, that runs in the UI thread, you can then place that data into the UI.

Comment: Then you have a problem with code that you haven't shown.  What you have provided so far wouldn't result in the UI thread being blocked.

Comment: @ Servy : it loads the tex file but the progressbar freezes and does not show indeterminate status. can you test my code and provide me a proper code as asnwer of my question ? thanks alot.

Comment: @SmartMan As I said, the code that you have provided will work fine.  Your problem is elsewhere in code that you have not shown.  I obviously cannot test code you have not provided, nor can I tell you how to fix it.

Comment: @ Servy : I have provied the whole of source code. do you want to check my wpfsample project ? i will upload it in mediafire ? if you have problem with that , let me know to upload it on your desire. thanks alot.

Comment: did you download the sample ? what is your idea ? it provides the whole source code i have posted in my question.